# Всё, несомненно, выглядело таким же как раньше это восхитительно!

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Скажите, пожалуйста, следует ли ставить в данном предложении запятые и если да, то как это обосновать?

Comment: Скажите, Вы спрашиваете только о тех запятых, которые *уже есть*? Или предполагаете, что *могут быть* ещё какие-нибудь запятые или другие знаки?

Comment: Предполагаю, что могут быть ещё запятые или другие знаки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем со слова [**несомненно**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/466/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE):
**1.** Вводное слово. То же, что «конечно, разумеется». Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. *Оставили бабушке рожки да ножки, рожки да ножки. Несомненно, песенка грустная.* М. Зощенко, Рассказы о Ленине. *Несомненно, она обладала хорошей памятью.* А. Куприн, Ю-ю.
**3.** Член предложения. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
*Положим, такая победа над смертью не может быть достигнута сразу, что совершенно несомненно.* В. Соловьев, Лермонтов.

Без контекста иногда сложно определить: нужны запятые или нет. В этом предложении, думаю, слово "несомненно" — вводное; ставим запятые.
А если бы на месте женщины был сердитый майор медицинской службы Уховертов, все, несомненно, кончилось бы совершенно благополучно. [Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек (1961)]

Теперь о конструкции [**такой(,) как**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722) (местоимение + союз).
По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
*Теперь, хлопче, скажу тебе, и бабы не такие, как прежде.* В. Короленко, Лес шумит.

Перед "как" ставим запятую.
― Я говорю "пять", потому что лично я помню себя пять лет назад точно таким же, как сейчас. [Виктор Пелевин. Желтая стрела (1993)]

Первый вариант
**Всё, несомненно, выглядело таким же, как раньше. Это восхитительно!**

Второй вариант (оборот с "как" закрываем запятой, ставим [интонационное тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91))
**Всё, несомненно, выглядело таким же, как раньше, — это восхитительно!**

Конечно же, возможны и другие варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что здесь есть несогласование по времени.

Вариант редактирования: *Всё, несомненно, выглядело таким же, как раньше, **и это было восхитительно!***

Comment: По-моему, здесь ещё и косяк сочетаемости: *выглядело таким же, как раньше*... Должно быть: *выглядело так же, как раньше* либо *всё выглядело таким же, каким было раньше*, разве нет?

Comment: А по-моему, нет косяка. Еще не прошло суток, но его лицо *выглядело таким, как* если бы он перенес горе. [А. С. Грин. Блистающий мир (1923)] Пламя костра *выглядело таким же замерзшим, как* и в Зале Двух Стихий. [Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и магический контрабас (2002)] P. S. Ответ НЕ ПО ТЕМЕ — ведь спрашивали о знаках. Мне было четко указано: если вопрос о пунктуации, то разбор предложения не требуется.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова у Грина звучит странно. Возможно, в то время воспринималось иначе. У Емца использован оборот "таким же [прилагательное], как..." — это совсем другое дело.

Answer (score -1):

Второй ответ (по комментариям)

**1. Как оформлен заданный вопрос**

Вопрос оформлен неудовлетворительно – ясно, что его писал неопытный участник. Такие вопросы  желательно редактировать, прежде чем отвечать на них, при этом не имеет смысла вступать в переговоры.

**2. Как оформлен ответ**

В ответе тоже не всё хорошо: он перегружен **лишней информацией**, при этом в нем отсутствует информация **необходимая.**

Лишней является информация **по вводным словам**, так как участник правильно обособил вводное слово. Но ничего не сказано **о правильности концовки,** а там явная грамматическая нестыковка по времени. Какой тогда смысл говорить о знаках препинания для ее оформления.

3. **Такой...какой или такой...как?**  Вопрос интересный и правомерный. Мне сочетание такой... как  на слух не показалось некорректным, но доказывать что-либо нужно с использование грамматики, а не только примерами.

В учебнике Кустовой сказано, что допустимы **оба сочетания**. Дело в том, что указательное слово «такой» имеет **«типизирующее» значение**, в отличие от указательного слова «тот».  Это значит, что оно не просто указывает на предмет (тот), а дает ему обобщающую характеристику, называя типичные признаки. Поэтому здесь допускается **сравнение и сопоставление**, то есть союз КАК, и поэтому происходит **контаминация** выражений: так…как и такой.. какой.

4. Редактирование **по основному вопросу** (согласование времени) я предложила, поэтому нельзя сказать, что мой ответ "не по теме, ведь спрашивали о знаках".

Comment: Мне кажется, контаминация упомянутых выражений — обычная речевая ошибка, ставшая нормой в связи с превалирующей языковой глухотой и тенденцией к дескриптивизму.

Comment: Вам кажется! А вот уважаемые лингвисты так не считают. Кроме того, объясняют причины явления вполне убедительно. Да и литераторы нормально относятся к обоим сочетаниям. Если просто описание, то такой...какой. Если есть сопоставление (а оно здесь есть), то такой...как.